# Comunicar R con javascript para un control de notificaciones

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Estoy creando una app shiny con la libreria shinydashboard.

Ahora mismo estoy probando lo que vienen siendo las notificaciones (mensajes alertas etc...)

Mi pregunta es como administras estas notificaciones (crear, modificar o borrar)
En la documentacion de shinydashboard indican como se crean por lo tanto en eso no hay problema, mi pregunta es como hago para que se elimine, por ejemplo, un mensaje cuando lo hayas visto o pulsado.

<s>Por ahora he probado con esto:</s>

**server.R**

```
output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
   from <- c("A","B")
   content <- c("Mensaje 1","Mensaje2")
    messages <- data.frame(from,content)
    msgs <- apply(messages, 1, function(row) {
        messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
    })
     dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs
    )
    
})
```

**app.js**

```
function mensaje(msg){
   alert(msg);
}
```

Evidentemente esto lo que hace es que cuando pulsas en el mensaje te sale una alerta con el contenido del mensaje, el problema es que me interesa que este mensaje se borre despues de verlo.

Por otra parte creo que hacerlo con js no es lo correcto ya que los cambios no se guardan en el data frame cuando lo haces.

## EDITADO

A partir de otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52355/como-cambiar-un-valor-de-un-datatable-cuando-es-pulsado) que formule, he podido gestionar (mas o menos) los mensajes, de forma que cuando pulsas en la tabla los marca como mensajes leidos.

Ahora bien, lo que me interesa es comunicar el js con la aplicacion (por ahora he enviado datos de la aplicacion al js pero no al reves).

Como podría ser muy amplia la respuesta os comento lo que tenia pensado mas o menos.

- Cuando pulsas la notificacion del mensaje lo marca como leido y actualiza el menu de notificaciones y la tabla de mensajes.
- Cuando pulsas la notificacion del mensaje te redirecciona a la tabla de mensajes.

Os dejo el codigo mas actualizado

**Server.R**

```
output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
    if(nrow(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),]) >0) {
        msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
            messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
        }) 
    }else{
        msgs = NULL
    }

    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
})

output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
    messages
})
observe({
    if(! is.null(input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected)){
        #browser()
        messages
        s<-input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected
        messages[s,"leido"] <<- TRUE
        output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
            if(nrow(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),]) >0) {
                msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
                    messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
                })
            }else{
                msgs = NULL
            }
            dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
        })


        output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
            messages
        })


    }
})
```

El js sigue siendo el mismo ya que no consigo entender muy bien como se comunica con `server.R`

**app.js**

```
function mensaje(msg){
   alert(msg);
}
```

No adjunto el `ui.R` ya que me parece que la información que hay ahi no es relevante.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No he trabajado con `shinydashboard`. Pero se puede mandar información de `js` a shiny usando la siguiente función en `js`

```
Shiny.onInputChange("nombre_input", valor);
```

Como sugerencia puedes usar el paquete `shinyjs` para mostrar alertas o correr cualquier código `js` desde el `server.R` de shiny.