# ¿Como cambiar un valor de un dataTable cuando es pulsado?

Tags: r, shiny

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con *shiny* y he creado un `data.frame` para los mensajes como si fuera un *inbox*.

Muestro los mensajes tanto en notificaciones como en una tabla de la libreria `DT`. Me gustaria que cuando pulses sobre ellos en la tabla cambie su valor leido a `TRUE`

Os dejo lo que he estado probando:

**Data frame mensajes**

```
from <- c("A","B","C")
content <- c("Mensaje 1","Mensaje2","Mensaje leido")
leido <- c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
messages <- data.frame(from,content,leido)
```

**DT::datatableoutput de mensajes**

```
output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
    messages
})
```

**Notificaciones de mensajes**

```
output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
    if(! is.null(input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected)){
        s<-input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected
        messages[s,"leido"] <- TRUE
    }
    msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
        messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
    })
     dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
})
```

Es en las notificaciones de mensajes donde compruebo si se ha pulsado y si es asi cambio su valor leido a `TRUE`, el problema es que no se guarda en el data frame como `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que crear un evento `observe` y asignar con `<<-`para que guarde el cambio

#### He cambiado el codigo un poco ya que habia un fallo que cuando ya no quedaban mas mensajes te daba el siguiente error:

> Error: subscript out of bounds

```
    output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
    if(nrow(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),]) >0) {
        msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
            messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
        }) 
    }else{
        msgs = NULL
    }
    
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
})

output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
    messages
})
observe({
    if(! is.null(input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected)){
        #browser()
        messages
        s<-input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected
        messages[s,"leido"] <<- TRUE
        output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
            if(nrow(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),]) >0) {
                msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
                    messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
                })
            }else{
                msgs = NULL
            }
            dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
        })
        
        
        output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
            messages
        })
        
        
    }
})
```